# Apache configurations for php "AddType text/html php" or "AddType application/x-httpd-php php .php"

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I am taking over an application server and discover that it contain the following settings:

```
AddType text/html       php
```

Although it works, but my understanding is that it should set as following:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php .php
```

What are the key differences between the two settings? Although at this point my application (Built using CakePHP) is running fine with either configuration, but I am not sure if it will cause any strange behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The mod_mime AddType definition from the [Apache httpd docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype):

> The AddType directive maps the given filename extensions onto the
>   specified content type. MIME-type is the MIME type to use for
>   filenames containing extension. This mapping is added to any already
>   in force, overriding any mappings that already exist for the same
>   extension. This directive can be used to add mappings not listed in
>   the MIME types file

In short `AddType text/html php` tells httpd to specify the Content-Type header for PHP files to be text/html.  Which is correct since it is used by the client side browser and not the server itself.

What tells httpd to handle the files as PHP is the [SetHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#sethandler) directive:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

The [PHP configuration instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) explain the SetHandler directive in relation to PHP as well.